# why do I need the network name between two routers for RIP routing?

Tags: cisco, routing, cisco-commands, rip

[the network in my exercise](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vqfKRQh_THfEyKIzjzVyz8iEofmMwRM4/view?usp=sharing)
I am learning about networks and I just started to learn about dynamic routing(like RIP) but there is something I didn't managed to understand and is why do I need in the "network" command to give the network name of the connection between the routers(16.0.0.0) in order to have network 15.0.0.0 to communicate with network 192.168.0.0 ?.

from what I understood all what you do here is to advertise other networks connected to the router to other connected routers. so why couldn't I just write "network 15.0.0.0" and "network 192.168.0.0" to make the routers know about each other's connected networks?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The network command tells RIP which interfaces should participate in the RIP process. If you do not include the link between the two routers in the RIP process, then RIP will not try to establish a connection across the link, and the routers will not advertise the networks to each other.

The `network` command does `not` tell RIP what networks to advertise, it tells RIP which interfaces are included. The addressing on the interfaces tell RIP what networks to advertise. This is true of most IGP routing protocols (BGP does it differently, advertising the network, if it already exists in the routing table).

Comment: so the "network" command just tells the RIP on what connection to advertise all of the networks connected to the router? and  writing "network 15.0.0.0" was pointless and only told the RIP to try to advertise the router's routing table to PC2?

Comment: Again, the `network statement` tells RIP which interfaces should participate in the RIP process. Any interfaces not included will not have the networks configured on the interface advertised, nor will any other RIP routers on those interfaces be updated. If you have interfaces where you want to advertise the networks on those interfaces, but there are no RIP routers on those interfaces, then you can use the `passive-interface` command to keep RIP from sending updates out those interfaces, but still get the network information from the interfaces.